# Strange json.stringify fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Strange is not the error itself but the way it happens. In my content editor while editing everything gets saved with unique id's in a javascript object and after you save in the end it gets json stringified. That work's for 99,99% of my users perfect but sometimes json.stringify didn't escape the quotes and its always happens with the same beginning. I really don't have a clue how this happens. Here is a picture of the javascript object:

http://cl.ly/image/3B3Z2e413M3r

Off course the marked line is the error but the whole thing (no escaped quotes) only occures if the content starts with this line. I should mention if you load a wysiwyg element in the editor there is a pre equipped < h3 >...< /h3 > and a < p >...< /p > with some sample data. (the h3 is not centered per default)

```
<h3 style="text-align: center;">Sample Headline</h3>
```

My problem is that i can't reproduce it. If i align my heading to get the same code, everything works well. Users got the last chrome version and there is no other plugin then jQuery.

Any ideas would be great because iam exhausted...

**Cliffnotes:**

- json.stringify failes to escape quotes and....
- everytime the error occurs to a user i see that it starts with the aligned heading so i guess it has something to do with it

Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

What you have shown is a normal JS object and not a JSON (so it has nothing to do with `JSON.stringify()`). The quotes must be only escaped in string literals in code, so that interpreter did not confuse it with delimiting quotes.

After it's parsed - they are stored in memory as-is without any escape characters.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/83GUe/

[image]

Guide: open developer tools, press `Run` and see the `Scope variables`

Conclusion: what you provided on a screenshot is a 100% expected and correct behaviour.

Comment: Hi zerkms, yes thats why it says a picture of the javascript object, not the actual json. I just marked the line where the json fails... here is the json code, sorry for confusing text. http://nopaste.info/102ea7b0f1.html

Comment: @user2190870: it stringifies it successfully http://jsfiddle.net/P8s55/ Any context information available? Like what is a browser used?

Comment: For me it works perfectly too. The user said he works with the latest version of chrome on mac.

Comment: @user2190870: "latest version of chrome on mac" --- then `JSON.stringify()` returns pretty much the same and valid result there as well.

Comment: i mean it gets stringified but it does not escape the quotes in the values, and this happens some times out of nowhere.

Comment: @user2190870: it's not possible. There is another (real) issue somewhere else (in your code).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/chickberger/6La2Z/ This is basically how i do it. At the end instead of a alert i save the stringified object to a textarea to save it in the database. i also double checked that no strip_slashes in php is active. btw thanks a lot for your help zerk :)

Comment: @user2190870: why do you serialize it on client-side actually? Why not send it form-encoded as it is done by default? And serialize on server if necessary.

Comment: Hmm i can save a object to the database without serialize it? That would be off course the best solution i only do this to get the object saved. I thought its the only possible way. EDIT: sorry misread. Yes that would be an option.